# Is there a better way to test that a script is being called in a controller other than expect_any_instance_of(#{ControllerClass}).to receive?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm fairly new to using RSpec, so there's a lot I still don't know. I'm currently working on speccing out a section of functionality which is supposed to run a script when a button is pressed. The script is currently called in a controller, which I don't know if there's a good way to test.

I'm currently using

```
expect_any_instance_of(ConfigurationsController)
  .to receive(:system)
  .with('sh bin/resque/kill_resque_workers')
  .and_return(true)
```

in a feature spec and it works, but rubocop is complaining about using expect_any_instance_of and I've been told to only use that method if there was no better way.

Is there any better way to test this? Like is there a way to get the instance of the controller being used, or a better kind of test for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better pattern would be to not inline the system call in your controller in the first place. Instead create a seperate object that knows how to kill your worker processes and call that from your controller. The [service object pattern](https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-service-objects-tutorial) is often used for this. It makes it much easier to stub/spy/mock the dependency and make sure it stops at your application boundry.

It also lets you test the object in isolation. Testing plain old ruby objects is really easy. Testing controllers is not.

```
module WorkerHandler
  def self.kill_all
    system 'sh bin/resque/kill_resque_workers'
  end
end

# in your test
expect(WorkerHandler).to receive(:kill_all)
```

If your service object method runs on instances of a class you can use [stub_const](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/mutating-constants) to stub out the new method so that it returns mocks/spies.

Another more novel solution is dependency injection via Rack middleware. You just [write a piece of middleware](https://ieftimov.com/post/writing-rails-middleware/) that injects your object into [env](http://webapps-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/rack/rack_env.html). `env` is the state variable thats passed all the way down the middleware stack to your application. This is how Warden for example works. You can pass env along in your spec when you make the http calls to your controller or use `before { session.env('foo.bar', baz) }`.